# Angular CLI: Where are dev bundle files located?

Tags: node.js, angular, ubuntu-16.04, lite-server

After having successfully run:

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/ng serve
```

My browser loads all kinds of bundle files, like `styles.bundle.js`, but where these files actually are locally? Running find in the project folder cannot find any of these.

Comment: If you want the bundled files, run `ng build` and look in `dist/`.

Comment: Yes, but it's a different thing.

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve with this?

Comment: There's no *problem*. I just want to know what's going on! My browser seems to load files that I cannot find.